# Xamarin.iOS project in Visual Studio 2017 giving error for Automatic Provisioning

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have crossplatform mobile app crated using Xamarin in Visual studio. I want to create Automatic Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS project through Visual Studio 2017. So I got to project properties and select "iOS Bundle Signing". Under "iOS Bundle Signing", I select "**Automatic Provisioning**" radio button and finally when i select Team it gives me an alert message "**Automatic signing failed, Please check the Xamarin output window**". When i look at output i get below message
Saving iOS Development certificates...
***There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project, please check the logs.***

Does anyone knows about this issue?

Comment: You can refer to the link https://blog.xamarin.com/automatic-provisioning-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT , the OP already mentioned he had selected a team, the final step in the post you provided, meaning he's all set up. I guess there's a problem in VS, I got the same error!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found no help anywhere.

I ended up:

1. Going to the Apple Dev site to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" page and removed any out-of-date profiles (and made sure I had a valid one still).
2. I then went into the "Debug" menu in Visual studio and selected "Options". In the left hand tree I went down and expanded "Xamarin" and then selected "Apple Accounts".
3. I then selected and removed my Apple account from the top panel and re-added it.
4. I then went back to the original iOS Bundle Signing tab in your Project properties. I switched to Manual provisioning and then back to Automatic provisioning and it worked!

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: For me it was a invalid certificate that VS was trying to update. Once i removed that it selected the correct cert to update.